# need a Maple program

Tags: maple

Write a Maple code in order to find all the at most three digits Pythagorean triples `(a, b, c)`, for
`a, b, c > 0`. We say that an integer triple`(a, b, c)` is a Pythagorean triple if `a^2+b^2=c^2`.
Hint: You might need to use the command `type(sqrt(x),integer)` as it returns true if `x` is a complete square. Get help for type from the help center.

Comment: Where have you gotten stuck with this assignment?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

one possibility. You can try to make it more efficient if needed.

```
result:=Array(1..999);
n:=0;
for a from 1 to 999 do
  for b from a to 999 do    
    c:=sqrt(a^2+b^2);
    if type(c,integer) and length(c)<=3 then       
       n:=n+1;
       result(n):=[a,b,c];
    fi;
  od;
od;
result:=result(1..n);
```

To print them

```
for item in result do    
    print(item[1]^`2`+item[2]^`2`=item[3]^`2`)
od
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
....
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score -1):

Consider this:

```
isolve(a^2+b^2=c^2);
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your code. This will confuse anyone who sees it firsthand

Comment: @mishsx How does my answer confuse? It is pure Maple code. Maple has built-in solution to the pythagorean triples problem. Have you used this code in Maple?